Approximation for the number of particles absorbed into the surface
I am working on a statistical physics problem where we consider a model with a container of an ideal gas with walls that can absorb particles. $r_0$ is the radius of particles, $N_a$, $N_b$, $V_a$, $V_b$ are respectively the number of absorbed and bulk particles, and their volumes. The volume of the absorbing surface can also be expressed as the area of the container, with a depth $V_b = A D$. The total number of particles is just the sum $N=N_a +N_b$, and $\epsilon$ is an energy particles in the wall gain. By setting the chemical potentials in the bulk and absorbed state we get the expression:
$$
\frac{N_a}{V_a} e^{-\beta \epsilon} \frac{1}{1-\frac{N_a \pi r_0^2}{A}} = \frac{N-N_a}{V_b}
$$
Which with the assumption that $N\gg N_a$ is supposed to result in:
$$
N_a \approx \frac{N}{\frac{V_b}{V_a}e^{-\beta \epsilon} + \frac{N \pi r_0^2}{A}}
$$
However, I completely unable to find out how one is supposed to arrive at this conclusion.

We have
$$\frac{N_a}{V_a}e^{—\beta\varepsilon}\frac{1}{1-\frac{N_a \pi r_0^2}{A}}=\frac{N-N_a}{V_b}$$
and we suppose that $N \gg N_a$ which means that $N-N_a \approx N$. As $N_a$ is very small, we can do a Taylor expansion of $1/(1-x) \approx 1+x$. Therefore
$$
\frac{N_a}{V_a}e^{-\beta \varepsilon}\left(1+\frac{N_a \pi r_0^2}{A}  \right)\approx \frac{N}{V_b}.$$
By rearranging the terms, we get
$$N_a \approx \frac{N}{\frac{V_b}{V_a}e^{-\beta \varepsilon}+\frac{V_b}{V_a}e^{-\beta \varepsilon}\frac{N_a \pi r_0^2}{A}}.$$
Once we get there, we're 3/4 of the way there. If we develop the formula a little further, we get
$$\frac{N_a}{V_a}e^{-\beta \varepsilon}+\frac{N_a^2 \pi r_0^2}{V_a A}e^{-\beta \varepsilon}\approx \frac{N}{V_b}.$$
Since $N \gg N_a$, the quadratic terme $\frac{N_a^2 \pi r_0^2}{V_a A}e^{-\beta \varepsilon}$ is much smaller than the linear term $\frac{N_a}{V_a}e^{-\beta \varepsilon}$. Neglecting the quadratic term, we simplify the equation to
$$N_ae^{-\beta \varepsilon}\approx \frac{V_a}{V_b}N \Longrightarrow N\approx \frac{V_b}{V_a}N_ae^{-\beta \varepsilon}.$$
We replace the expression for $N$ found and obtain
$$N_a \approx \frac{N}{\frac{V_b}{V_a}e^{-\beta \varepsilon}+\frac{N\pi r_0^2}{A}}.$$
